# dynamic height css sticky footer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sticky-footer

I was looking recently for a dynamic css sticky footer solution and came across this one:
http://pixelsvsbytes.com/examples/sticky-footers-the-flexible-way/simple.html

it seems to work great in most of the popular newer browsers that i've tried but for some reason chrome doesn't display it in the same way and my guess is that safari acts in the same way.

can anyone point a finger on where the problem might be?

Thank you.

Comment: I followed the link and the footer sticks fine in chrome and safari

Comment: the footer sticks fine but the header doesn't stay at the top like in the other browsers

Comment: It's possible this is a bug; removing `display: table` and adding it back gets it to display correctly

Comment: you are correct! any way around it? i could use jquery to change it onload but I'd rather not...

Answer (score 3):

ok I solved it thanks to Explosion Pills comment.

It is most likely a bug if you set the body tag display property to be `display: table`.

to solve it just place the elements inside another div tag and set it as `display: table`

Comment: The main problem with burying the content inside another div, of course, is that the extra div(s) which are used only to coerce the layout are non-semantic elements--they have nothing to do with the *data*, and as layout elements they are out of place in a modern web page observing proper separation of concerns.  FWIW.